# Can a google marketplace app integrate with the google Drive UI?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

So I'm developing a Google Marketplace application for my company. In addition to several other features, my boss wants the app to be able to integrate with the Google Drive UI (eg be able to open files from the UI using the app). Now I understand that it's quite possible to use the Google Drive API to pull information from Drive to our Marketplace app, but is it actually possible for a Marketplace App to integrate with the Drive **UI**, for instance in the manner described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and there are many apps on market place that uses Drive UI to create or open file such as [Docusign](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=14522%202630554804398764274), [draw.io](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=18806%2014512935155953175632), and [gantter](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=4968%209776296785720246484).

Please take a look at this GDL about [integrating Drive API with Google Apps Marketplace](https://google-developers.appspot.com/live/shows/31225111-2001). This will give you basic idea of how to use Dirve API with Google Apps Marketplace.

Also, take a look at documentation about [Drive UI](https://developers.google.com/drive/enable-sdk).

Comment: Okay, so in the video he mentions a hybrid model for adding the 'install' scope to your application, but I'm confused by how you would add that scope to your app if you can't go through the manifest. He gives an example of prompting the user to click a link to add the install scope to the application, how would that work?

Comment: Alright I've found it out. To take the approach suggested in the GDL and add the 'install' scope to your app manually you can add the code found in the "Handling authorization requests" section at [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-client) to one of your html files. Then add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install` scope to the SCOPES variable and link the `handleClientLoad()` function to whatever event you want to trigger the installation.